# Is there a way to use SQL query that would return results if values can be in any order?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, search

My code let me perform search, as long as the order of the words is correct.

Let's say I'm searching for `big dog`, but I also want to search for `dog big`. It get more complicated with 3 or more words.

Is there a way to create a SQL query which would let me search through values with any order?

Only way I can think of this is by having multiple queries, where I change order of PHP variables manually...

```
    <?php

        if(isset($_GET['query']) && !empty($_GET['query'])) {
            $query = $_GET['query'];
            $query_array = explode(' ', $query);

            $query_string = '';

            $query_counter = 1;
            foreach($query_array as $word) {
                $query_string .= '%' . $word . (count($query_string) == $query_counter++ ? '%' : '');
            }

            $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE Name LIKE '$query_string'";
            $result = sqlsrv_query($cms->conn, $query);

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
                extract($row);

                echo '<a href="'.$Address.'.html">'.$Name.'</a><br>';
            }

            sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
        }
        else {
            //echo 'NO GET';
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assemble your conditions and check for each word on it's own:

```
$query_array = explode(' ', $query);
$queryParts = array();
foreach ($query_arra AS $value){
   $queryParts[]="Name like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."%'";
}

$searchString = implode(" AND ", $queryParts);
```

The Search string would now be `Name like '%big%' AND Name like '%dog%'` ... depending on how much search-keywords have been there.

I use the same approach very often, also when it is required that ALL keywords appear in at least ONE of the columns. Then you need one more loop to create the required `AND` conditions:

```
$search = "Big Dog";
$keywords = explode (" ", $search);
$columns = array("Name", "description");

$andParts = array();
foreach ($keywords AS $keyword){
  $orParts = array();
    foreach($columns AS $column){
      $orParts[] = $column . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($keyword) . "%'";
    }
    $andParts[]= "(" . implode($orParts, " OR ") . ")";
}
$and = implode ($andParts, " AND ");

echo $and;
```

this would produce the query part `(Name like '%Big%' OR description like '%Big%') AND (Name like '%Dog%' or description like '%Dog%'`)

So, it will find any row, where `dog` and `big` are appearing in at least one of the columns `name` or `description` (could also be both in one column)

Comment: This is great! But, is there a way to make this work with prepared statements? I do not have an access to MYSQL real escape string method.

Comment: @HelpNeeder yes you could do this for prepared statements as well. Simple replace the insertion of the keyword with the proper placeholder and make sure you maintain the correct placeholder / value assignment in an seperate array, so you can bind the values correctly later on.

Answer (score 2):

Since your original querystring is something like `%big%dog%`, so I assume you are okay with matching `big wild dog`. In this case, you can just use the `AND` operator.

```
(Name LIKE '%big%" and Name LIKE '%dog%")
```

Comment: I think OP was using big and dog as an example.  He called out having "3 or more words" as well.  Granted you could turn the above into a dynamic sql query but it's going to get super expensive super fast with all those `and like '%%'`s  You'd likely be better off using full text search I would think for situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

myisam supports full text search:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: oh, and Innodb in late version mysql as well.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could look into is Full Text Search for ms sql server.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

it's similar to a "search engine" in that it works off of an algorithm to rank results and even similar words (think thesaurus type lookups)

It's not *exactly* trivial to set up, but it's easy enough to find a tutorial on the subject and how to query from FTS (as the syntax is different than say LIKE '%big%dog%')

Here's a sample query from the page linked above:

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM products 
WHERE CONTAINS(product_description, ”Snap Happy 100EZ” OR FORMSOF(THESAURUS,’Snap Happy’) OR ‘100EZ’) 
AND product_cost < 200 ;
```